# Referencing a worksheet through a cell value - Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, worksheet

I'm doing a `vlookup` with the matrix to search in another worksheet which name is `may-18` (I have other worksheets with name `apr-18`, `mar-18`, `feb-18`, `jan-18`). The problem I'm facing is I want to refer the worksheet through the value of a cell (In cell `A1` I have written `'may-18`). For example:

```
=VLOOKUP(C4,'may-18'!$C$6:$BY$28,7,FALSO) # Current
=VLOOKUP(C4,'apr-18'!$C$6:$BY$28,7,FALSO) # Current
=VLOOKUP(C4,'mar-18'!$C$6:$BY$28,7,FALSO) # Current
=VLOOKUP(C4,'feb-18'!$C$6:$BY$28,7,FALSO) # Current
=VLOOKUP(C4,'jan-18'!$C$6:$BY$28,7,FALSO) # Current

=VLOOKUP(C4,'A1'!$C$6:$BY$28,7,FALSO) # Looking for this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INDIRECT()`:

```
=VLOOKUP(C4,INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!$C$6:$BY$28"),7,FALSO)
```

Note: This assumes `A1` has `may-18`, `apr-18`, etc. in the cell (note the lack of a leading apostrophe, which you put in your OP. I assumed that is a typo).

Comment: it's not a typo, because if I write without the apostrophe excel will take/transform it to date, but if I write it with the apostrophe excel takes the value as a string. And a string is what I need to do the formula in order to refer the name of the worksheet.

Comment: @Chris - Ah I see.  The formula I put should work. If not, remove the leading `" ' "` and just use `...Indirect($A$1&"'!$C$6...`

Comment: @Chris - Ah, I had a typo in my formula. Use the formula in my answer, it works for me.